# how thin is the top layer of a mortar shower pan

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, drain, mortar

[I am planning on building the top layer of my shower pan on top of a faulty old one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101309/can-i-use-my-old-shower-pan-instead-of-a-mortar-base-layer/101312#101312).  assuming I remove the old mortar surrounding the drain and it leaves me a depression deeper then 2 inches.  how thick is the rest of the top mortar layer suppose to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top layer should be 1 1/4″ to 1 1/2″ thick.
http://floorelf.com/how-to-create-a-shower-floor-part-4
it can be 3/4″, but it has to be reinforced with metal lath beneath it attached to the substrate(in the comment section from the same source)